# How can I do a recursive merge of YAML maps in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

According to the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html), the merge key only merges based on the top level keys, ignoring values with existing keys. However I have a use case where I'd like it to merge recursively. For example, given the YAML:

```yaml
src_dict: &sd
  a_key: {a_bool: true, an_int: 1}
  another_key: "some value"
merge:
  <<: *sd
  a_key:
    a_str: "some deep merge data"
```

I'd like to get:

> `{'src_dict': {'a_key': {'a_bool': True, 'an_int': 1}, 'another_key': 'some value'}, 'merge': {'a_key': {'a_str': 'some deep merge data', 'a_bool': True, 'an_int': 1}, 'another_key': 'some value'}}`

but the result is:

> `{'src_dict': {'a_key': {'a_bool': True, 'an_int': 1}, 'another_key': 'some value'}, 'merge': {'a_key': {'a_str': 'some deep merge data'}, 'another_key': 'some value'}}`

I'm trying a couple of approaches. The first is a custom YAML mapping object that would preserve all content, however I'm not seeing any relevant accesses so far with the following code:

````
import ruamel.yaml as _yaml

dbg = lambda *args, pre="dbg:": [
    print(*((pre,) + args)),
    args if len(args) > 1 else args[0]
][1]

yaml = _yaml.YAML(typ="unsafe")


@_yaml.yaml_object(yaml)
class RecMer:
    """Recursive Merge YO."""

    items = {}
    yaml_tag = "rec_mer"

    def __init__(self, a_dict):
        for k, v in a_dict.items():
            self.items[k] = v
        return

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ["items"]:
            print(f"Visiting: {name} in RecMer[{hash(self)}]")

        if name in ["__dict__"]:
            breakpoint()
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        dbg(key, pre="in __getitem__:")
        return self.items[key]

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.items.copy()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        d = self.items
        d.update(state)
        return


def test_recursive_merge_yaml_object():
    sample = """
src_dict: &sd
  #!<rec_mer>  # breaks if both are used at once
  a_key: {a_bool: true, an_int: 1}
  another_key: "some value"
merge:
  !<rec_mer>
  <<: *sd
  a_key:
    a_str: "some deep merge data"
""".strip()
    # rmd = RecMer({"a_key": {"a_bool": True, "an_int": 1}})
    # dbg(f"```{yaml.dump(rmd)}```")
    assert "a_bool" in dbg(
        yaml.load(sample),
        pre="!<rec_mer>:",
    )["merge"]["a_key"], "recursive merge failed"
    return
````

as running the test yields:

```
Visiting: __setstate__ in RecMer[8758280833597]
Visiting: __setstate__ in RecMer[8758280833597]
!<rec_mer>: {'src_dict': {'a_key': {'a_bool': True, 'an_int': 1}, 'another_key': 'some value'}, 'merge': {'a_key': {'a_str': 'some deep merge data'}, 'another_key': 'some value'}}
in __getitem__: a_key
AssertionError('recursive merge failed')
```

The second approach is to monkey-patch relevant classes in `_yaml.contructor`, however that hasn't yielded anything positive as yet.

What am I missing? Am I on a good track with any of these approaches? Or is there a better way?

Comment: IMO you should not use try to assign new behaviour to a well defined merge key. Define a new key (e.g. `++` and do the processing by some recurisively called function after loading.

Comment: @Anthon That's a good point. I've already created a working patch, but I'll take another look and see about defining a new key. Thanks.